# bootstrap 4 tabs around the page and inside the tab content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Can we do a design like below example , **i need to create with only html, css, bootstrap 4 tabs**, i 
 have seen many examples but i didn't found any solution , can any one give the reference one , please 
 provide me the reference one that will be a great help. please give me any solution how to achieve ...can you please send me any reference example like below image mentioned

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance , if any one accept my request, give me just idea how to acheive

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">TAB 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">TAB 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">TAB 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can use the bootstrap grid layout to achieve this effect.

You will have your regular container class with a row and then a column, the first row of 12 images will each consist of 1 column each.

While the subsequent rows will have a 1 column for the left image, one column for the right image and a 10 column image in between.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then for the left image and the right image you could do the following

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can then add your picture in the regular fashion, you can set the size and padding and margin as you desire. Take note that, that middle class can be anu number of columns equal to 10.